# Django filter returns duplicate values

Tags: django

I have `Post` model linked with `Vote` model in one-to-many relationship. when i try to filter posts with most votes `.filter()` returns posts duplicated as many as the votes it received
i tried to understand & use `.distinct()` function as recommended in similar questions but it doesn't turn out to be working.

here's the Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=450)
    posted_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    posted_at = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, default=timezone.now)
    status = models.CharField(choices=status, default='PENDING', max_length=15)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

& Vote model:

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{str(self.user)} - {str(self.post)}'
```

views.py:

```
class PostsView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'posts.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['most_voted_posts'] = Post.objects.filter(status='PUBLISHED').order_by('-vote')

        return context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first annotate each `Post` in your queryset with the number of votes by using [`Count`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#id8), using this annotation on a vanilla/non-filtered queryset should not produce duplicates. Then you can order by this annotation:

```
from django.db.models import Count
Post.objects.annotate(num_votes=Count('vote')).order_by('-num_votes')
```